# Speed & Pitch Shift calculation for cassette recorded at 9.5 cm/s

Tags: cubase, analog, pitch-issue, 4-track

I am extracting some of my old 4 track cassettes onto my computer using a 2 track deck (the only cassette playing I have left). It seems that at one point I had a Tascam 4 track that recorded at a speed of 9.5 cm/s (3 3/4 in/s).

Can anyone help me work out what Speed and Pitch shift values I need to use (I'm using Cubase to record them onto my PC) to restore them to their original playing speed and pitch.

Answer (score 3):

After some more research I learnt that the "ubiquitous cassette" speed was/is 4.75 cm/s (i.e. half the speed of my recordings). After finding this out I punched the numbers into this site http://www.thewhippinpost.co.uk/tools/tempo-pitch-calculator.htm whereby the bpm increase is doubled (bearing in mind I need to speed up my recording as my input speed was half the recorded speed) resulting in a pitch shift of + 1 octave - which I guess kind of makes sense - I just wasn't sure if there was a direct/simple correlation between speed and pitch but it turns out there is.

Instead of using Cubase - I applied this using Wavelab's Pitch Correction which I didn't realise would work one out from the other - i.e. you can change the pitch and if the Length Compensation is set to 0% it will act "like a tape recorder" and double the playback speed at the same time.